# No results on layered navigation when filter applied

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, layered-navigation

In Magento2 - We have a Multi-Store site with product category pages, with some attributes enabled in layered navigation.

The fact is that in certain stores, filters counts shows the items per filter correctly but when the filter is applied no product is displayed.

How can we debug this?

**Edited:**
Debugging it with **Magento Profiler**, I have found the only query that contains the filter field name on it and it seems that the problem is that the store_id is concatenated in the query with a wrong unexciting store id. How can I find where this store_id is appended to the query?

**Edited2:**
It seems that is due to something wrong in the database, since creating the whole Web Site with its Store and Store View again makes it work correctly.

Comment: Can you try to reindex once?

Comment: Tried with no luck